# Prove that $2^x+1$ is always greater or less than $3^\frac{x}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is any way to prove that 
for any real number 
$2^x+1 > 3^\frac{x}{2} $
or $  2^x+1 < 3^\frac{x}{2}$

I tried using differentiation but it doesn't help any more due to $2^x$ and $3^\frac{x}{2}$ .

Comment: please do not make edits which make the answer appears off topic.

Answer (score 3):

We want to prove
$$2^x+1>3^{x/2}=\sqrt3^x.$$
For $x<0$, we obviously have
$$1>\sqrt3^x,$$
and for $x>0$,
$$2^x>\sqrt3^x.$$

Comment: You can also take the logarithm, considering that $\log(2^x+1)\ge(x\log2)\max0>x\log\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=2^x+1 - 3^\frac{x}{2}$$  What could be noticed is that $$f'(x)=2^x \log (2)-\frac{1}{2} 3^{\frac{x}{2}} \log (3)$$ cancels for $$x=-\frac{2 \log \left(\frac{2 \log (2)}{\log (3)}\right)}{2 \log (2)-\log (3)}\approx -1.61697$$ and, for this value $$f(x)=1-3^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\log (3)}{\log (4)}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}}+4^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\log (3)}{\log
   (4)}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}}\approx 0.914629 $$ This point corresponds to a minimum by the second derivative test; at the point where $f'(x)=0$, the value of the second derivative is $$4^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\log (3)}{\log (4)}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}}
   \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{4} 3^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\log (3)}{\log (4)}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}} \log ^2(3)\approx 0.0325052$$ So, for any $x$, $f(x) >0$ and, even better, $f(x) > 0.91462$.

Meanwhile I was typing this junk, came Yves Daoust's nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

$2^x>3^{\frac x2}\iff \left(\dfrac2{\sqrt3}\right)^x>1=\left(\dfrac2{\sqrt3}\right)^0$ i.e., if $x>0$ as $\dfrac2{\sqrt3}>1\iff 2>\sqrt3$

Comment: What about $x<0$ ? (there is a $+1$)

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, we know that $4>3$. Take the square root both of sides, we have $2>\sqrt{3}$. Then ...

**EDIT:**

**The original question is** *proving that $2^x$ is always greater than $3^{x/2}$*.

Answer (score 0):

$2^x = 4^{x/2}$. So you are asking whether $4^{x/2}+1 > 3^{x/2}$.

It's obviously true if $x ≥ 0$. If $x < 0$ then $3^{x/2}<1$, so it's also true.